# is there a way to make a get method in a for loop in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm making a code to use for loop with a frame inside and a get method also inside.

```
for question, answer_choice, correct_choice, correct_answer in zip(questions, answer_choices, correct_choices, correct_answers):
    #frameQ=Frame(root)
    frameQ=Frame(root)
    frameQ.grid( row=rn , columnspan=4, sticky="w")
    Entry_answer=Entry(frameQ)
    Entry_answer.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky ="w")
    user_answer=Entry_answer.get()  #===this is not working
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tkinter has a great way to deal with input. It introduces new variable types. For example, you can use StringVar() in this case. StringVar() have the specificities of updating anything related to them when they are updated. For example,

```
var = StringVar()
entry = Entry(frame, textvariable=var)
entry.grid(column=x, row=y)

label = Label(frame, textvariable=var)
label.grid(column=x, row=y)
```

In this case when you update var with the entry the label is updated automatically. I think this is what you are aiming for. As you can see I used the textvariable option to do this. You can see all the other options for widgets at the [official tkinter documentation](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/entry.htm). I would also suggest you go on [this website](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/widgets.html#entry) It has a great tutorial to learn about tkinter. Lastly, you forgot to say in which column you want the frame to be. That may also resove a problem.

Comment: how do I get values of var? how do is set the var? I try to use this code:Entry_answer.bind(sequence='<Return>',func=lambda event,    user_answer=user_answer,rn=rn:obtain(rn,user_answer))                                                                                                 def obtain(rn,user_answer):
        user_answer.get()  
        user_ansf.append(user_answer);

Comment: this is the values of print ( user_ansf) [<tkinter.StringVar object at 0x0000014AAC33CE80>]
[<tkinter.StringVar object at 0x0000014AAC33CE80>]
[<tkinter.StringVar object at 0x0000014AAC33CE80>]
[<tkinter.StringVar object at 0x0000014AAC33CE80>]
[<tkinter.StringVar object at 0x0000014AAC33CE80>] but I need the string value

Comment: To get the value of a StringVar() you do :     `var.get()`        To set the values of a StringVar() you do :      `var.set()`     I do not really understand why you would bind that much to a key.